# Perform operation on python list without using global variables

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a python list (e.g. `lst = [2, 3, 5]`). Corresponding to each element of `lst` , I want to construct a numpy matrix in the following manner: it should be a square array of the same size as the considered element of the `lst`, and should be filled with squared value of that element.

This is how I am approaching the problem at present:

```
import numpy as np
lst = [2,3,5]
for i in range(len(lst)):
    globals()['mat'+str(lst[i])] = np.full( (lst[i],lst[i]), lst[i]**2 )

print globals()['mat'+str(2)]
print " "
print globals()['mat'+str(3)]
print " "
print globals()['mat'+str(5)]    

[[4 4]
 [4 4]]

[[9 9 9]
 [9 9 9]
 [9 9 9]]

[[25 25 25 25 25]
 [25 25 25 25 25]
 [25 25 25 25 25]
 [25 25 25 25 25]
 [25 25 25 25 25]]
```

What is an efficient way to do this task without using global variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't an efficiency issue here, regardless of how you name or generate the arrays.  Regardless of the naming, you have to use `np.full` for each array.  Once you've created an array you can collect it in a list, a dictionary or assign it to a variable.

I would collect the arrays in a list:

```
In [212]: lst = [2,3,5]
In [213]: lst1 = [np.full((i,i),i**2) for i in lst]
In [214]: lst1
Out[214]: 
[array([[4, 4],
        [4, 4]]), array([[9, 9, 9],
        [9, 9, 9],
        [9, 9, 9]]), array([[25, 25, 25, 25, 25],
        [25, 25, 25, 25, 25],
        [25, 25, 25, 25, 25],
        [25, 25, 25, 25, 25],
        [25, 25, 25, 25, 25]])]
```

If you must assign names use something like:

```
In [215]: mat2, mat3, mat5 = lst1
In [216]: mat3
Out[216]: 
array([[9, 9, 9],
       [9, 9, 9],
       [9, 9, 9]])
```

That `globals()[]` trick works, but is not good Python programming practice.  It looks more like a carry over from the world of BASIC than idiomatic Python.  Collect things in lists and dictionaries, not dynamically generated globals.

Speaking of dictionaries, we can convert the list to one with:

```
In [217]: adict = {f'mat{i}': x for i,x in zip(lst, lst1)}
In [218]: adict
Out[218]: 
{'mat2': array([[4, 4],
        [4, 4]]), 'mat3': array([[9, 9, 9],
        [9, 9, 9],
        [9, 9, 9]]), 'mat5': array([[25, 25, 25, 25, 25],
        [25, 25, 25, 25, 25],
        [25, 25, 25, 25, 25],
        [25, 25, 25, 25, 25],
        [25, 25, 25, 25, 25]])}
```

(Here I'm using the newish `f-literal` string syntax.)